# Getting an unknown space in between various images added together

Tags: html, css

I need to have text displayed in a transparent image that resembles like an area painted using paint brush. So I cut the edges and have 8 in all,
top left, top middle, top right
left
right
bottom left, bottom middle, bottom right

And text coming in between. Can someone suggest what I'm missing here?

Attached screenshot for the reference. Notice the white line around the text.[image: screenshot]

Adding HTML code

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Banner Test</title>
        <style>
            
            .banner-content {
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
              width: 70%;
              left:50%;
            }
            .banner-content .top {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_topmiddle.png");
              background-position: top center;
              background-repeat: repeat-x;
              min-height: 21px;
              position: relative;
              top: 0;
              float: left;
              width: 100%;
              display: block;
            }
            .banner-content .top:before {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_topleft.png");
              background-position: top left;
              left: -50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
            }
            .banner-content .top:after {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_topright.png");
              background-position: top right;
              right: -50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
            }
            .banner-content .middle {
              position: relative;
              background-color: rgba(137, 38, 120, 0.85);
              float: left;
              width: 100%;
              display: block;
              text-align: center;
              color: #fff;
            }
            .banner-content .middle h1 {
                font-size: 35px;
            }
            .banner-content .middle::before {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_leftmid1.png");
              left: -50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
              background-repeat: repeat-y;
              background-position: left center;
            }
            .banner-content .middle::after {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_rightmid1.png");
              right: -50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
              background-repeat: repeat-y;
              background-position: right center;
            }
            .banner-content .bottom {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_bottom1.png");
              background-position: bottom center;
              background-repeat: repeat-x;
              min-height: 31px;
              position: relative;
              z-index: -1;
              top: 0;
              float: left;
              width: 100%;
              display: block;
            }
            .banner-content .bottom:before {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_bottomleft.png");
              background-position: bottom left;
              left: -50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
            }
            .banner-content .bottom:after {
              background-image: url("img/Paintstrip-subhead_bottomright.png");
              background-position: bottom right;
              right: -50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="banner-content">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="middle">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We'll need code please

Comment: HTML code added. Should I add the images here as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue.

```
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Transform is causing those lines to appear. So I just need to remove this and then re-apply the top margin.